# Alfresco share login issue

Tags: java, alfresco

I found some issue with my local installation of alfresco share. When I try to login using

http://localhost:8080/share

it returns to me this error message:

```
The remote server may be unavailable or your authentication details have not been recognized
```

On my log I can see that:

```
12:02:28,491 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Java version: 1.6.0_26
12:02:28,492 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Java vendor: Apple Inc.
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Java class path: /Users/andrea.girardi/Documents/Works/Project/alfresco-3.4.e/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Operating system name: Mac OS X
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Operating system architecture: x86_64
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Operating system version: 10.7.1
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunPKCS11-Darwin 1.6: SunPKCS11 accessing Mac OS X SmartCardServices
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SUN 1.6: SUN (DSA key/parameter generation; DSA signing; SHA-1, MD5 digests; SecureRandom; X.509 certificates; JKS keystore; PKIX CertPathValidator; PKIX CertPathBuilder; LDAP, Collection CertStores, JavaPolicy Policy; JavaLoginConfig Configuration)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] Apple 1.0: Apple Provider (implements DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC/MD5, HMAC/SHA1)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunRsaSign 1.5: Sun RSA signature provider
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunJSSE 1.6: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunJCE 1.6: SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunJGSS 1.0: Sun (Kerberos v5, SPNEGO)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunSASL 1.5: Sun SASL provider(implements client mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5; server mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] XMLDSig 1.0: XMLDSig (DOM XMLSignatureFactory; DOM KeyInfoFactory)
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] SunPCSC 1.6: Sun PC/SC provider
12:02:28,493 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpClient] BC 1.45: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.45
12:02:28,523 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpConnection] Open connection to 172.24.110.5:8080
12:02:28,526 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] >> "GET http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/remotestore/has/alfresco/site-data/configurations/slingshot.site.configuration.xml?s=sitestore HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,526 http-8080-1 DEBUG [commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase] Adding Host request header
12:02:28,534 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,535 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,535 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] >> "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,535 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] >> "[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,537 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] << "HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )[\r][\n]"
12:02:28,537 http-8080-1 DEBUG [httpclient.wire.header] << "HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )[\r][\n]"
```

I found on forum some clue to fix that issue changing the tomcat port from default 8080 to another but, moving to 8081, I can see the same issue.

How can I fix that? I'm using 3.4.e on my local Mac and 3.4.d on remote Windows 2003 server.

it seems to be a proxy error,

```
"HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).
```

Another question, on Windows server I can see that error log message:

```
WARN : org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl - WQS unable to connect to repository: Cannot access http://127.0.0.1:10080/alfresco/service/cmis: Connection refused: connect
```

any suggestion?

thanks for your time!

Andrea

Comment: are you sure that your alfresco server is running? Share need an Alfresco instance up, what happen when you go to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/ ?

Comment: yes it's running, I'm able to login to localhost:8080/alfresco

Comment: and do you launch alfresco and share using the same tomcat?

Comment: yes I did. Default installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem. As wrote on Alfresco forum, "Share will not let you log-in if the Explorer application is either not running correctly or running on a port other than 8080 and you haven't told Share where to find it. You must get Explorer (/alfresco) working before attempting to run Share".

thanks for your time,
Andrea