# Error while trying to log into Alfresco Community Edition

Tags: alfresco

After installing Alfresco Community Edition (4.2.c) in my office machine, I get 
**"The remote server may be unavailable or your authentication details have not been recognized."**

But it installed properly and can log into in my personal laptop. I want to know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Is this same : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7793855/1064610

Comment: But without any configuration changes it runs in my personal laptop. I have installed WAMP server in my laptop and XAMPP server in my office machine. So I change the port 8080 to 8082.  Also as in stackoverflow.com/a/7793855/1064610 http://localhost:8082/alfresco does not work for me

Comment: what does it mean that it doesn't work for you? which error do you have?

Comment: When i tried to log into the system (http://127.0.0.1:8082/share/page/) it gives "The remote server may be unavailable or your authentication details have not been recognized." error in my office machine.

Comment: alfrescoPostgreSQL service does not start. When I tried to start it through the control panel -> services, it gives an error message "process terminated unexpectedly"

Comment: Have you got another Postgres server already running? Otherwise try checking the Postgres logs, if the event log doesn't help.

Comment: On a more general point you should always post your `alfresco.log` if you have problems starting up the server. Although if the DB is not starting then clearly you should fix that first.

Comment: I reinstall alfresco. now tomcat and postgre servers are running. But still I have the same issue when i try to log in (127.0.0.1:8082/share/page). And in the share.log it gives the below error --> [org.alfresco.web.site.EditionInterceptor] Unable to retrieve License information from Alfresco: 404

Comment: I use XAMPP server in my machine too. I stopped all the service and reinstalled alfresco

Comment: my alfresco.log is too long to post. how can I post it here.

Comment: @WillAbson I got the same error while installing 4.2 e, I cannot login to share nad my explorer says resource not available. How to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check if the repository part is up and running by logging to

```
http://localhost:8082/alfresco
```

If this doesn't work (as you said? What happens?) you should check alfresco.log and maybe catalina.out for obvious errors. Maybe use tcpview from Sysinternals to check if the ports are not claimed by other programs (Skype e.g. has the annoying behaviour to grab port 8080).

If this is fixed, you should be able to login to /share also (unless you forgot to adjust the ports for the endpoints in share-config-custom.xml...)

Comment: http://localhost:8082/alfresco is not working. it gives (HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco) error. I changed the port 8080 to 8082 since i use XAMPP server as well. In share-config-custom.xml also port is mentioned as 8082

Comment: So you should check your Tomcat Setup: is alfresco.war at the right place? Has it been "exploded"? Anything in catalina.out about startup of alfresco context? I remember one occasion where web.xml mysteriously disappeared from the exploded alfresco/ directory on one Alfresco server, causing a nasty 404 error (nasty because everything looked OK on first sight and no obvious error in the logs :-/ )

Comment: Thank You very much all of you for helping me to solve my problem. That issue happen due to the low performance of my machine with the Windows XP os.