# Alfresco not able to access alfreco explorer

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, alfresco, mysql-connector, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco . I have installed alfresco 4.2.e on ubuntu laptop . I am not able to access alfresco explorer using

http://localhost:8080/alfresco

Its says Http Status 404 error.

Also i am able to access   http://localhost:8080/share . But on this page i am not able to login.

As Share will not work until the /alfresco webapp is running correctly.

I have gone through some post

[Alfresco Service Forum RESTFul API not working properly (empty results and 404s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914082/alfresco-service-forum-restful-api-not-working-properly-empty-results-and-404s)

[Alfresco share login issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737652/alfresco-share-login-issue/7793855)

[Error while trying to log into Alfresco Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216944/error-while-trying-to-log-into-alfresco-community-edition)

http://element14.wordpress.com/2007/07/05/howto-install-alfresco-on-linux-sharepoint-alternative/

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/alfresco-not-able-to-open-in-internet-browser-840259/

But didn't get solution.

My catalina.out shows

```
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
2016-03-25 15:08:07,561  WARN  [solr.core.SolrCore] [localhost-startStop-1] [archive] Solr index directory '/home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/alf_data/solr/archive/SpacesStore/index' doesn't exist. Creating new index...
 2016-03-25 15:08:07,901  WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
 2016-03-25 15:08:08,985  WARN  [solr.core.SolrCore] [localhost-startStop-1] [alfresco] Solr index directory '/home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/alf_data/solr/workspace/SpacesStore/index' doesn't exist. Creating new index...
 2016-03-25 15:08:09,101  WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
 Mar 25, 2016 3:08:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/tomcat/webapps/share.war
2016-03-25 15:08:22,941  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2016-03-25 15:08:23,035  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 2016-03-25 15:08:23,036  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2016-03-25 15:08:23,041  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,341  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 353 Web Scripts (+0 failed), 367 URLs
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,341  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 8 Package Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,342  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered 0 Schema Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,535  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntimeContainer] [localhost-startStop-1] Initialised Spring Surf Container Web Script Container (in 2481.7234ms)
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,539  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2016-03-25 15:08:25,542  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [localhost-startStop-1] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 Mar 25, 2016 3:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 25, 2016 3:08:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-03-25 15:08:41,179  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alfrescomdm' with user 'alfrescomdm'.
 2016-03-25 15:08:41,218  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorityBridgeTableCache' defined in class path resource [alfresco/cache-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in file [/home/varun/alfresco-4.2.e/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantAdminDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/dao/dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'repoSqlSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectResourceLoader' while setting bean property 'resourceLoader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectResourceLoader' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#2e385de5' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'dialectClass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean#2e385de5' defined in class path resource [alfresco/ibatis/ibatis-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect' defined in class path resource [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '&sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'localSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceCheck' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.DataSourceCheck]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Database connection failed: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
```

Comment: I guess you need to add mysql driver dependency to your classpath

Comment: @YounesRegaieg, Recenty i have installed ubuntu 14.04LTS. The output of    **echo $CLASSPATH** shows nothing. Also **/etc/environment** show value of only PATH. I inserted the following in /etc/environment file. 
`CLASSPATH="/usr/share/mysql:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar"` Is there anything i need to do..?

Comment: You could always [try reading the official Alfresco documentation on configuring Alfresco for MySQL and following the well-explained step-by-step guide they give](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/mysql-config.html)...

Comment: @Gagravarr Worked thanks

Comment: Side-note: If you must run 4.2, which is now a very old version, you really should be running 4.2.f because it contains an important security fix for 4.2.e. Do not deploy 4.2.e to production. See https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Community_4.2.f_Release_Notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - [you need to read and follow steps in the official Alfresco documentation on configuring Alfresco 4.2 for MySQL](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/mysql-config.html). (Similar documentation is available for the other Alfresco versions too, eg [Alfresco 5.1](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/mysql-config.html))

As that will guide you through, you need to download the MySQL Connector for Java jar file (which due to a long standing licensing dispute with Oracle hasn't been shipped by Alfresco as standard in quite a few years), then drop that jar into your Tomcat lib folder so that it's available to Alfresco. You'll then likely need to edit your `alfresco-global.properties` file to tell it about your MySQL database details

Alternately, you could switch to PostGreSQL (the Alfresco recommended option for an open source database to use with Alfresco), and [follow these instructions for installing the jdbc driver and configuring it](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/postgresql-config.html) to work.